# Using session to determine if its signup or signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my case scenario:

**Note**: When you are newly signing up, you fill the form, it takes you to welcome page and you click a button to proceed which takes you to settings page to set up your profile before you have access to the application.

**Note**: That the app session is 5 hours if actively signed in

However, when user sign up, and they get redirected to WelcomePage, and at the moment lets say for an example emergency happen and he or she did not complete the signup stages by proceeding to then next stage which is settings, when he/she gets back, he/she gets redirected to settings page

**Here is what I have done below and it doesn't work for me when user that left on emergency and gets back, which is suppose to take him/her to settings path/page.**

**What I have done but doesn't work**

I created a new method in application controller and passed it into create action to redirect to that path, however I don't think its best solution.

**sessions_controller** create action

```
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      @member = Member.from_auth(auth_hash)
    end

    if @member
      if @member.disabled?
        increase_failed_logins
        redirect_to signin_path, alert: t('.disabled')
      else
        clear_failed_logins
        reset_session rescue nil
        session[:member_id] = @member.id
        save_session_key @member.id, cookies['_peatio_session']
        save_signup_history @member.id
        MemberMailer.notify_signin(@member.id).deliver if @member.activated?
        if @member.disabled?
          redirect_back_or_settings_page # here is the method
        else
          redirect_back_to_success_page # here is the method
        end
      end
    elsif (!verify_recaptcha)
      redirect_to signin_path, alert: t('.put_capture')
    else
      increase_failed_logins
      redirect_to signin_path, alert: t('.error')
    end
  end
```

**corresponding method in application controller**

```
def redirect_back_or_settings_page
  if cookies[:redirect_to].present?
    redirect_to cookies[:redirect_to]
    cookies[:redirect_to] = nil
  else
    redirect_to settings_path
  end
end


def redirect_back_to_success_page
  if cookies[:redirect_to].present?
    redirect_to cookies[:redirect_to]
    cookies[:redirect_to] = nil
  else
    redirect_to signup_success_index_path
  end
end
```

How do I go about dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on "for an example emergency happen"? If something can break in this that would otherwise affect the signup process. I would wrap the whole thing in a begin...rescue block to ensure that they are always given the correct response from the server.

You also want to ensure that the actually state of their "user" is persisted in the database. If something goes wrong on the front end, it should not affect what the server knows. Never trust the client.

Here is how login should flow:

1. User comes to login/signup (either form)
2. Credentials are entered and sent to either end point.
3. If the data base says these credentials are correct, store a hash in your session store, send a cookie down with an expiration time and their user id and a hash of some sort. Preferably a JWT. And issue a redirect_to url
4. Any subsequent call should verify if the cookie exists, recalculate the hash from the cookie, and check if the hash is the same in your session store. If it is, serve the content, otherwise, redirect them to login.

Have you heard of devise, btw? Makes this a lot easier.

Cheers!